# Retrieve SQLite Entry in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, http, flask

I'm using SQLite with Flask for the first time and trying to retrieve the data I just inserted into my database. My POST request which inserts JSON data into a database works fine (or at least does not return errors).

I'm trying to display whatever I inserted to verify and doing it as follows:

```
cur = db.execute('select * from places order by id')
entries = [dict(lat=row[0], long=row[1], address=row[2], name=row[3]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
return entries
```

I'm getting an error 500 back. Why is this happening? I was only able to find two examples of doing and they are both doing what I have above.

**EDIT:**

Here's Flasks's error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1361, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1450, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 711, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 55, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/Users/nayef/.virtualenvs/uber-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 818, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Are you running Flask in debug mode? It should give you more information than just a 500 error.

Comment: Please see the update with Flask's debug info.

Comment: Hm. Doesn't seem like the problem is with the code you posted. What happens if you remove it? What are you returning `entries` to? Please post more code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try return `return repr(entries)`. Your views should return strings not list objects. For whatever reason if you return a list flask will try and call it and you will get a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` error.

Comment: Thanks! One thing: the return string doesn't seem right. Here's what is being returned: `[{'lat': u'{', 'address': u'a', 'id': 1, 'long': u'l', 'name': u't'}]`. Here's what I posted: `{'lat':5, 'long':10, 'address':'street', 'name':'work'}`. Is that an encoding issue? How would I fix it?

Comment: I'd post a new question describing that because it's a different issue that your facing. In the new question put the python code that posts to the db as well as the code that retrieves, and describe what the expected output was and what you actually got.

Comment: Would you recommend using SQLAlchemy instead?

Comment: I  would recommend using Django, it's ORM makes it so easy to deal with the database. SQLAlchemy looks really great too, but I have no personal experience with it.

Comment: I need to use Flask for this actually :-/. Flask has a nice documentation on SQLAlchemy but it appears to use SQLAlchemy, I need to write Flask using classes and views as opposed to just using functions with @app.route above of it. So I probably need to learn that now and take a stab at SQLAlchemy. SQLite with Flask has zero documentation online.